# Fatal error on using java npm package

Tags: java, node.js, ubuntu, meteor, npm

I am using 'node-excel-api' npm package inside my Meteor application. It has dependency on 'java' npm package. I am getting the following error on startup of Meteor server.

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

Internal Error (threadLocalStorage.cpp:56), pid=3880, tid=3074959104
guarantee(get_thread() == thread) failed: must be the same thread, quickly

JRE version:  (7.0_45-b18) (build )
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode, sharing linux-x86 )
Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping,
try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

An error report file with more information is saved as:
/home/support/sTemp/excel-support/node-excel-api_Sample/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/hs_err_pid3880.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
=> Exited from signal: SIGABRT
```

I doubt the problem is with environment settings in my machine but I couldn't figure out the reason for the same. I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and oracle java 7(/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/). I have set the JAVA_HOME env variable and also have JAVA_HOME\bin in PATH variable.

Could anyone please help me in solving the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uh... A quick google search shows [one bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4822846) with this error message but it dates back to 2003! Which JDK is installed? Can you try with another one?

Comment: @fge - I have seen this bug page. I noticed that the affected version mentioned in it is 1.4 ie Java 4. But I am using Java 7(you can see it in the error log in the question).

Comment: Yes, I have seen that... Which is why I asked you if you could try another JRE/JDK (sorry if that wasn't clear)

Comment: I tried installing and using openjdk-7-jdk. But the problem persists. :-(

Comment: But is OpenJDK actually used (ie, the version you see in the output is OpenJDK)?

Comment: I updated the JAVA_HOME path with that of openJDK but still in the error it is showing the 7.0_45-b18 which is the oracle java 7 version. I don't know from where it is been referenced.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you have set up java correctly and environment variables are  being correctly exposed.

In fact the error is detected at cpp code which is a wrapper for the JVM. The JVM's thread management is some very intricate work and has to be done very properly.

Node on the other hand is single threaded.

Meteor uses fibers and that's something that already puts a layer on top of node's single threaded architecture.

Naturally, java npm package seems to have a problem with fibers.

See this issue: https://github.com/joeferner/node-java/issues/38 and voice your concern so that the developers prioritize this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I had a look at the open and closed issues of node-java package. I find that similar issues have been raised before and closed. But the information from that is not satisfying for me. So I have raised a new issue. https://github.com/joeferner/node-java/issues/106

Comment: No problem, if you agree that this indeed is a bug and that this answer is correct, please mark it as the accepted answer. And it would be great if you come back to edit/update this answer when the issue is resolved.